# Magento 1.7 Grid Default

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, product-list, grid-layout

How do I set Magento 1.7 to default of grid view? I have selected in administration to grid default but is not working

Answer (score 1):

The latest selected mode is always stored in the session, so to see the default view after you have changed the configuration, you have to delete your session cookies.